# Did Jesus undergo another temptation in the the garden?

Tags: life-of-jesus, temptation

The only temptation I know of in the bible concerning Jesus was when in the wilderness with the devil. A friend used Mel Gibson's Passion of the Christ as his basis to claim Jesus was tempted by the devil (with the appearance of a snake) while praying.

I kind of thought, personally that it made sense to why he needed the disciples to help him in prayer. He had to go back for the third time to pray with sorrow and heaviness untill an angel came to strengthen him.

> "And there appeared an angel unto him from heaven, strengthening him.
>   And being in an agony he prayed more earnestly: and his sweat was as
>   it were great drops of blood falling down to the ground." (Luke
>   22:43-44).

Is it a mere spiritual reason to this claim that he was strengthened by an angel from heaven as if in a struggle or there are actual biblical references that support a spiritual encounter with the devil? If there was an encounter, how and why?

Answer (score 7):

The Bible does not definitively state whether or not Jesus was tempted in the garden or not, so for us to be definitive where the Bible is not must be speculative at best.

What we do know is that Jesus was tempted during His life in all ways, just as we are, yet was without sin.

> For we do not have a high priest who is unable to sympathize with our
>   weaknesses, but one who in every respect has been tempted as we are,
>   yet without sin.  (*Hebrews 4:15 ESV*)

This doesn't mean that Jesus experienced every temptation anyone has ever experienced, but that He was tempted in the same ways that we are.

It should also be noted that Satan is not the only source of temptation.  There are, of course, other demons, but temptation also comes from our own sinful flesh, apart from demonic influence.  Now, in this case, if there were any demonic temptation, Satan himself would probably have thought it worth his time.  Yet, we just don't and can't know for sure.

So, Jesus experienced distress, as the Scripture tells us, but we don't know for sure whether or not He experienced temptation at this particular moment, although it's quite possible and perhaps even as much as probable.

Comment: +1 thanks for that verse. I recall Don Moen's song 'Emmanuel' which a part says "tempted in everyway, yet without sin

Comment: As well as Mel Gibson, [Nikos Kazantzakis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095497/) obviously thought this was a distinct possibility.

Answer (score 2):

As lining up with a response of mine to another question, it is clear that he is tested in his humanity, since he does not want to die (living is a good thing.) Death is an evil that the human recoils from naturally. This 'natural' recoiling is overcome, it would seem, by doing something even better, that is, the will of God, which ***is life itself***. If this counts as a 'temptation' in your analysis, then there is your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Jesus was tempted in the Garden because of the suffering He was about to endure for mankind. He asked the Father to take this cup (possibly of suffering) from Him, nevertheless He asked for the Father's will to be done. He submitted to God and resisted what He wanted (not to suffer) and what Satan ultimately wanted (for Jesus not to die for mankind). As for dying, He knew that He was returning to the Father in Heaven. I would see no reason for His dying and returning to heaven,to be upsetting to Him.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see what makes a Q&A SE site different from the rest of the internet.  In particular, answers benefit from being supported.  (In this case, citing the scripture regarding taking the cup would be a supporting reference).  Your closing sentence looks to be mostly opinion; please take a look at [how to write a good answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as an aid to editing/revising/upgrading your answer.  Thanks for joining in; we hope you'll browse other Qs&As on topics of interest to you.